# regex breaks on \n

Tags: javascript, regex

segmentText = ;

```
testRgx = [/( \d+\.| [^\W\d_]\.|.)+?([!?.。](?= |$)|$)/g];


arrSegments = segmentText.match(testRgx);
```

This expression fails if segmentText has \n or other white spaces in it.I want to add 
\n in to the list of chars that the above pattern use
[!?.。] => [!?.。\n] so that the segment is separated based on the \n character

Answer (score 2):

If you add the 'm' modifier the . will match newlines

```
/foo/gm
```

Comment: The `m` modifier causes `^` and `$` to match at line boundaries.  It's `s` that causes the dot to match newlines, but JavaScript doesn't support it.

Comment: hi Alan Moore ..I did not understand the comment..can you please elaborate.How can I make it so that it does not break on \n ?

Comment: Sourabh - See my answer for a solution to not breaking on `\n` in js

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there is no 's' modifier, so for instance if you want to match things inside quotes in the following text:

```
something foo bar "
porky" something bar foo
```

You could normally use `/".+?"/s`. Instead in JS you would use `/"[\s\S]+?"/` - matching **every** character, as the dot will match all but newline characters.